# Копирование с другим владельцем

Tags: linux, shell, консоль

Как в терминале Linux с помощью команд `mv` или `cp` скопировать или переместить файл или папку так что бы при переносе у них был уже другой *владелец* и *группа* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cp` не поддерживает смены владельца при копировании. Вы можете сменить владельца файла после копирования:  `cp srcfile /home/user/Documents ; chown user:user /home/user/Documents/srcfile`. Если же Вы хотите именно смену владельца и копирование одной командой, почитайте про утилиту `cpio` - альтернативу `cp`.

Comment: назвать `cpio` «альтернативой» `cp` можно с очень большой натяжкой... прежде всего это всё же утилита для работы с архивами, а `pass-through` режим всё же предназначен для подготовки оных.